# Netbeans: Never remove specified static imports

Tags: java, netbeans

I am developing with LWJGL at the moment, and even though against coding standards, it is better to statically import all `gl*` methods such that you can access all methods easily as the `GL11`, `GL12`, ..., `GL44` works incemental, so there is never code duplication amongst packages.

Now I have the following:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL14.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL21.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL31.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL32.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL33.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL40.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL41.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL42.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL43.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL44.*;
```

But of course I am not using them all, however I need them for auto suggest to be able to resolve any `gl*` method. I like the *Remove unused Imports* function from Netbeans aswell.

Is either of the following possible?

- Have a setting such that *Remove unused imports* does not touch **any** static import.
- Have a setting such that I can specify which imports Netbeans should not touch with *Remove unused imports*?

Comment: AFAIK, no. But I guess we'll wait for someone more knowledgeable to answer.

Comment: Look here about a workaround with a *source template*: http://www.richardnichols.net/2013/01/dealing-with-static-imports-in-netbeans-ide/

Comment: @PeterMmm It's a decent option to add them back, would need some additional checking if an import is already available or not, but it would be a last resort.

Comment: Even imports within `editor-fold` are not safe to *Remove unused imports*

Comment: "Duplicity" means dishonesty or deception. The word you're looking for is "duplication".

Comment: @Spire Thanks for the comment, I fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way that *works*, though I would actually not recommend anyone to do so, but I'm just sharing it because it works.

Inside the `class` you add the following:

```
static {
    int KEEP_IMPORTS = GL_2_BYTES | GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE | GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE | GL_BLEND_COLOR | GL_ARRAY_BUFFER | GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_LENGTH | GL_COMPRESSED_SLUMINANCE | GL_ALPHA_INTEGER | GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_BLOCK_MAX_NAME_LENGTH | GL_ALREADY_SIGNALED | GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED | GL_ACTIVE_SUBROUTINE_UNIFORM_MAX_LENGTH | GL_ACTIVE_PROGRAM | GL_ACTIVE_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFERS | GL_ACTIVE_RESOURCES | GL_BUFFER_IMMUTABLE_STORAGE;
}
```

This takes the first `final int` from every `GL11`, `GL12`, etc. and *uses* it, now Netbeans does not complain anymore.